# Java HashSet and HashCode for custom object that contains a list

Tags: java, linked-list, equals, hashcode, hashset

i have the following situation:

```
    public class CustomClass {
       private LinkedList<ActionClass> actionList;
       private MyReaderClass reader; //methods...
       //other methods...
       hashcode()
       equals()
       //blabla
    }
```

Now, i use the customclass inside an hashset but i haven't understand if it's needed the implementation of the methods hashcode and equals also inside the ActionClass because of the fact that it is contained inside the linked list that i used. 
Thanks for responses

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please can you expand your example code to show how you are using `CustomClass` more concretely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you want to use your `CustomClass` as element of HashSet collection, you have to provide `hashCode` method. And to get really unique hash code for your object, you have to calculate it including hash codes of all object's fileds. In your case, including `actionList`'s hash code.

Due to JavaDoc for [List#hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode%28%29):

> Returns the hash code value for this list. The hash code of a list is defined to be the result of the following calculation:
>
> ```
> int hashCode = 1;
> for (E e : list)
>  hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
> ```

That means, that you have to provide the hashs (`hashCode()` implementation) for your `ActionClass` too, in order to calculate a the hash code for the collection.

The same is true for the [List#equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), if you want to add your class to some other Collections, which do not require the object's hash:

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal.

You have to provide the implementation of `equals()` method in your `ActionClass`, to make the 2 variable of type `LinkedList<ActionClass>`  comparable with each other.

Sure, you can avoid of using the `actionList` field in your `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementation of the `CustomClass`, if you are sure, that it's value is not omportant for your `CustomClass`. But anyway, it's a "good style" to provide the implementations for both this methods in your classes.